# Automatically submit input on page open with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

I have this code

```
var file = getUrlVars()["file"];
    if(file){
            document.getElementById('search').value = file; 
    }
    function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}
```

It reads the parameter file from url and then puts the value in the search field.
The search field is ajax powered, when a user enters a letter it starts searching and outputs results. 
The problem is that when the scripts puts the value in the search field nothing happens, how do i make the search to fire up?

This is my search field

```
<input type="text" id="search" class='search_input' />
```

**UPDATE:**
My Ajax search code is this

```
// Search
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".search_input").focus();
        $(".search_input").keyup(function() 
    { 
    var search_input = $(this).val();
    var keyword= encodeURIComponent(search_input); 
    var yt_url='http://domain.com/search.php?q='+keyword;  
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: yt_url,

        success: function(response)
    {
        $("#result").html('');
        if(response.length)
        { 
            $("#result").append(response); 
        }
        else
        {
            $("#result").html("<div id='no'>No results</div>");
        }
    }   

    }); 
    });
}   );
```

Comment: Your search is triggered by a keyup event, which isn't going to happen if you're setting the field programmatically.  Consider using a `change` event instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your search will only "*fire*" if the event that initilizes the AJAX functionality is triggered. Thus, you need to trigger the event. My wild guess is the event is bound to either:

```
 - keyup
 - click
 - blur
```

You haven't posted the relevant code, but that should be enough of an answer...

---

**After your update**

A quick solution is to initiate the `keyup` event on the search field:

```
$(".search_input").keyup(function() { ... }).keyup();
```

Or, you could re-factor the code:

```
function searchlogic() { ... };

$(".search_input").keyup(searchlogic);

searchlogic();
```